# How many unity version support with 1 seat?

Tags: unity

I bought plus unity license 1 seat so Can I use it on 2 unity version Example:
Uity5.3.4p3 and unity 20183.18f1
Or it use only for one version?

Comment: You keep asking questions that can be answered by consulting Unity's licensing FAQ or support sites, which may be why your questions are attracting down-votes. Please take time to research the available documentation to see if your answers are already out there — it will both help you get your answers faster, and more authoritatively (since it will be straight from the source) as well as ensure your account does not experience negative repercussions such as question bans for low-scoring questions.

Answer (score 1):

1 seat means you are licensed for one developer to develop with the Unity platform, any version(s).

You may not have more than one developer without purchasing additional seats.